# Is "I will back myself up myself" correct?

Tags: word-usage

Can I say *I will back myself up myself*? I want to use the first *myself* to refer to *I* (myself) and I want to use the second *myself* to emphasize *I* as the subject of a sentence.

I want to say that no one backed me up and I backed myself up myself (on my own). Is that sentence correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely best to avoid repetition of 'myself' at all costs. That second 'myself' is superfluous. The first myself (as long as it's emphasised) does the job on its own. Try saying the following sentence out loud, putting the emphasis on 'myself'.

> I will back *myself* up

I understand from that that you will do it on your own.

If you think that doesn't quite do the trick, you might consider adding a short phrase to clarify. For example:

> I will back *myself* up - I don't need any help.

(In your question you used both 'will' and the past tense, so modify the phrase accordingly.)